# Copy only files and only lines containing a string while preserving directory structure

Tags: grep, find, file-copy, recursive

Say I have a directory that contains other directories and files. I want to search for a string in each file and copy only the matching lines to another location while preserving directory structure.

For example, say I have this structure

```
dir
  subdir1
     file1.txt
  subdir2
     file2.txt
```

and

`file1.txt`:

```
abc

def
```

and

`file2.txt`:

```
ghi
```

Now I want to get only matching lines from the files that contain 'de', so the outcome I want should look like this:

```
dir
  subdir1
     file1.txt
  subdir2
```

and

`file1.txt`

```
def
```

Comment: This is more a programming question (be it in `bash`) than a Linux question: you may consider posting it on StackOverflow instead. (However I won't flag anything here as some people will think of a conditional `grep`-supported `find` to do just that there :) ).

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `find(1)`, `xargs(1)`, and `grep(1)`:

- duplicate the directory structure:

  ```
  src=/path/to/source
  dest=/other/path/to/destination
  pat='some_grep_pattern'

  cd "$dest"
  find "$src" -type d ! -path "$src" -printf '%P\0' | xargs -0 mkdir -p
  ```
- copy files with the given pattern:

  ```
  cd "$src"
  grep -rlZ "$pat" | \
      (cd "$dest"; \
      xargs -0 sh -c ' \
          while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do \
              grep "$pat" "$src/$1" >"$1"; \
              touch -r "$src/$1" >"$1"; \
              shift; \
          done' sh)
  ```
- restore permissions, assuming Linux, and assuming you don't have filenames with embedded newlines:

  ```
  cd "$src"
  getfacl -RPe . | (cd "$dest"; setfacl --restore=-)
  ```